# How can I locate a game object by name in unity studio?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I locate a game object by its name in Unity Studio ? I dont mean in code but actually looking at the Unity UI I want to locate in one of the scenes a game object by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do:

1. If you know the name of the game object that you are looking for:

You can use the search bar above your game object list.
[image]

2. If you know the name of any assets that attaches with the game object:

You can right click on the assets attached to the game object from the Assets area and choose "Find references in Scene", it will high light the game objects that is using that assets, so that the results can be narrowed down.

[image]

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[There is](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Searching.html) a documentation about searching on unity editor but there is not too much to learn because it is a common search component that you can find on some view segments like project, hierarchy, scene viewport, etc... each one with one scope for searching into ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on the object in the hierarchy window while holding the Alt key.